# Conversion Enum to Boolean type

Tags: c++

In my application i want to represent AND as 1 , and OR as 0, instead of opting for `#define` method , i am using enum to represent them , as shown in the below example program

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum gateConnection_t
{AND,OR}
gateConnection;

int main()
{

bool and_t = AND;
bool or_t = OR;

printf("%d\n",and_t);
printf("%d\n",or_t);

return 0;
}
```

As seen above , i am directly assigning the enum values to boolean vvariables. The program works as expected and my only question is whether the internal cast done is safe , or is it  better to use explicit casting such as `static_cast` ?

Comment: What's the point of this?

Comment: @mwerschy c++ , sorry for tagging C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, your {AND,OR} are the wrong way round.

Enums by standard start at 0 (although you can override that).

Use

```
enum gateConnection_t
{OR,AND}
```

instead.

The cast is safe by the way.

Conceptually though it's a nasty thing to do. Why do you want this; particularly in C++? What's wrong with true and false?

Comment: yes , it was intended as an enum with AND = 0....I have to do this to represent relationship between two signals , the decision to use 1 and 0 is abitrary , with no particular reason

Answer (score 1):

```
enum gateConnection_t
{AND=1,OR=0}
gateConnection;
```

or

```
enum gateConnection_t
{
OR=0,
AND  //<== this equal to the previous plus one automatically 
}gateConnection;
```